# Getting the text value of an EL expression variable?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, el

I have an EL expression i.e.

```
data = #{zoo.cat.weight}
```

How can I get String value: "zoo.cat.weight"

Is there an method for it?

Comment: Why would you want that? Where do you want that?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of `#{zoo.cat.weight}` from a ManagedBean? If is the case,  you only need have declare your cat and getWeight and only do reference from your bean

Comment: In an xhtml page. I'd like to add paramater to a functiont.
Instead of x = #{factory.f(data)} ------->


x = #{factory.f('zoo.cat.weight')}